# Cant list custom type posts based on category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, get-posts

Hi,

I want to list posts which belong to custom type "news" under a certain category. This is my code:

```
<?php
$news = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'news',
    'category' => 83
) );
 
if ( $news ) {
    foreach ( $news as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

I get nothing from this and I checked the category ID and its correct. If I use a 0 instead then it lists all posts regardless of their category but any other number will list nothing. Why is that?

Please notice that these custom type posts are categorized under a custom taxonomy called news_category.

Thank you.

Comment: Why have you got `category` _and_ `taxonomy`? The latter isn't even a recognized argument.

Comment: I tried taxonomy only to see if it helped but no use. It wont work with or without it.

Comment: help please????